# Large RoR project migration from Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.8.7+ solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After updating to Snow Leopard, Ruby 1.8.7 (preinstalled with OS) become much more closer to me. I try to use port's but has no luck with this solution. (port ryby186 halt something without drop exception).
So I start to think about update large scope of code to 1.8.7 requirements. Please help me with some scripts, articles and so on whose help to analyze code.

I already try to read release notes on http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/activity/ruby-18?from=2008-12-07 , but without any positive results.

Thank You for answers!

Comment: This question does not have anywhere near enough information to answer effectively.  You should ask about specific issues with your migration instead.

Answer (score 1):

As AB suggested, your question is hard to answer specifically. If you are dealing with switching from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7, you'll want to have both installed on your machine. You might look at a tool to manage multiple versions of Ruby such as [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It is packed as a gem, so install it:

```
sudo gem install rvm
```

Then to get Ruby 1.8.6 back, run:

```
rvm install ruby186
```

With rvm you can also set up gem sets so that it is easy to keep your sets up to date on the different versions of Ruby you install.

Comment: Ok, but maybe special special code analyzer available, which may parse code and show capability issues?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing automatic that you could just run on your project. A complete test suite would no doubt go a long way towards telling you what broke.

Answer (score 0):

You can also migrate application to 1.9.x using [one9](https://github.com/cldwalker/one9) and of course [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) as mentioned by Jared. It's worth a try as 1.9.x is already available and 1.8.x will be abandoned someday.